# How to get multiple Module configs auomatically to different folder using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, tfs, automation, msbuild, azure-devops

I have Multiple folders, for Example, www contains Folders A, B, C and So on and this same structure exist in a different environment like INT, REG, DR, PROD.  each contains different web.config.

So Here comes the challenge we need to provide an automated way to check-in each web.config.

Named like web_A_int.config, web_A_REG.config , Web_A_Prod.config, Web_A_DR.config and Web_B_int.config , Web_B_Reg_config and so on .

The environment is TFS (2015) Source Control and solution is .net based solution.

Please let me know if anything you might need to understand the question.

How to maintain this structure post build compilation. or How we can use proj or Powershell script to achieve it?

Desired Output:
INT--> www--> A, B,C Folders and each web.config placed inside respective folder.
REG--> www--> A, B, C --> with each web.config and each module level placed correctly.

Comment: It looks like an interesting question, but I think it's too broad in its current form. Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777) and show what you've tried so far, ideally in the form of an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to use web transforms and create a web.{environment}.config file and then apply that transformation on deployment.

The Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations) should get you started on how to use web transforms. I can provide you with some Powershell code on how to do this if that's how you decide to go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar web server deployment in TFS, but here are some regular powershell functions you could use to build loops:

```
$environmentTypes = @('INT', 'REG', 'DR', 'PROD')

Function Get-WebConfig([String]$Path)
{
    try {
        $configContent = Get-Content \\path\to\config\file
    }
    catch {
        Write-Debug "ERROR: Could not get content of $($Path)" 
    }

    return $configContent
}

Function Create-FolderStructure() {

    [cmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateSet('INT','REG','DR','PROD')]
        [String]$EnvironmentType,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$Server,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String[]]$FolderNames,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [Switch]$CheckServerUp
    )
    Begin {}
    Process {
        try {
            if($CheckServerUp)
            {
                try {
                    Test-Connection -ComputerName $Server
                }
                catch {
                    Write-Debug "ERROR: Unable to test connection to $Server"
                }
            }

            foreach($item in $FolderNames)
            {
                try {
                    New-Item -Path "\\$Server\c$\www\$item" -ItemType Directory

                }
                catch {
                    Write-Debug "ERROR: Unable to create folder $item"
                }
                try {
                    switch($EnvironmentType)
                    {
                        'INT' 
                        {
                            $neededConfig = Get-WebConfig -Path \\path\to\your\intconfig
                            break
                        }
                        'REG'
                        {
                            $neededConfig = Get-WebConfig -Path \\path\to\your\regconfig
                            break
                        }
                        'DR'
                        {
                            $neededConfig = Get-WebConfig -Path \\path\to\your\drconfig
                            break
                        }
                        'PROD'
                        {
                            $neededConfig = Get-WebConfig -Path \\path\to\your\prodconfig
                            break
                        }

                        try {
                            New-Item -Path "\\$Server\c$\www\$item\Web_$EnvironmentType.config"
                            Set-Content -Path "\\$Server\c$\www\$item\Web_$EnvironmentType.config" -Value $neededConfig
                        }
                        catch {
                            Write-Debug "ERROR: Unable to create file"
                        }

                    }
                }
                catch {
                    Write-Debug "ERROR: Unable to get web config content"
                }
            }
        }
        catch {
            Write-Debug "ERROR: Could not get content of $($Path)" 
        }
    }
    End{}
}
```